# How to remove text from a string after a specific character?

Tags: python, path, strip

My program is like the command prompt (cmd) but much simpler. I am creating a command called, `'bd'` which stands for back (one) directory. There is a path string: `path = "C:/Program Files/node.js"` and I want to remove the last directory `'/node.js'` but I don't want to use indexing or slicing, because the path string will change on the file's name length.

I have tried `path.rstrip("/")` but I couldn't figure how to remove the last `'/'` with the directory name, `'node.js'`.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the only way i can think of is to use `path.split(/)` and reassemble the string afterwards
it would look something like this:

```
path: str = "C:/Program Files/node.js"
splitup_path: list = path.split("/")
new_path: str = ""
for i in range(path.count("/")):
    new_path += f"{splitup_path[i]}/"
print(new_path)
```

Comment: Could you break down explain how the for loop works?  I've been over it several times and don't understand how it works. Thanks.

Comment: so first you split up the original path that results in having a list of all directory names without the "/". than you create a loop that does one loop less than there are objects in the list splitup_path (i just saw i used the false type hint i will change it) you can acheve this by counting the caracter you used to split the string before (thats was 'path.count(/)' is doing) but you coud also do this by using 'len(splitup_path) - 1' than you take the Dir Name and append it to the new path inside of the loop after that you append a "/" (thats was the f str is doing)

Comment: Hey @radiirgummii can u try my code & check if you are getting outputs or not pls...Idk why OP not getting output

Answer (score 0):

Use path lib

```
from pathlib import Path
fpath = "C:/Program Files/node.js"
   

p = Path(fpath)

print(str(p.parent))
```

output

```
C:\Program Files
```

Comment: When I run this code, I get this error:

AttributeError: partially initialized module 'pathlib' has no attribute 'Path' (most likely due to a circular import)
>>>

Comment: Edited the it's maybe due to var conflict

Comment: Try this & Let me know as soon as possible

Comment: What do you mean, 'edited the it's'?

Comment: Typo mistake: I mean I've edited It's may be due to variable conflict

Comment: Ahh so should I try the new code?

Comment: Yes...Try edited code

Comment: I got the same error somehow

Comment: create a separte .py & can u try again...It's working for me absolutly fine

Comment: I'm still getting the same error on a new .py file but @
radiirgummi has helped me resolve the error. Thanks for your time.